# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: when using parallel stream to add elements to List

Tags: java, java-stream

I am working to optimize some processing of an csv file , therefore trying to accelerate some Jackson implementation.
So I have:

```
List<T> testResults=new ArrayList();
Stream<T> testStream= Streams.stream(TestIterator);
testStream.parallel().forEach(p->testResults.add(p));
```

and here i get :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 360145
at java.util.ArrayList.add(Unknown Source)
at xml_test.opencsv.App.lambda$1(App.java:85)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachTask.compute(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.CountedCompleter.exec(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doInvoke(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateParallel(Unknown Source)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateParallel(Unkno
```

Any ideas whats going on? If  I remove the 'parallel' it works , but is extremely slow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html) is not a thread-safe implementation. One solution is to wrap it with [`Collections.synchronizedList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList(java.util.List)):

> Returns a synchronized (thread-safe) list backed by the specified list.

```
List<T> testResults = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
```

Comment: Better is to use the idiomatic solution: `List<T> testResults = testStream.parallel().collect(Collectors.toList());`